# My clean url script on .htaccess is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess script that works on my local machine but the problem is when I uploaded it on my hosting which runs a cpanel the script doesnt work like what I expect it to.. Does Local and Uploaded .htaccess has difference?
here is my .htaccess script

```
RewriteRule ^/                                      index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?p=$1
```

Am I mistaken on something here or do I need to configure something on my cpanel??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex page.php index.php

## RewriteCond Set here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?p=$1    [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi I tried your script and my site became unreachable any explanation why?